# Prevent manual control of pivot control movement

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-interface

I've got a pivot control with a number of pages in it. Each page has some controls in it, for example a textbox.

I've read around and I KNOW that it's bad practice to put controls like this in a pivot but I'd really like to do it.

The application switches between pivot pages automatically but the user is able to move the pivot control manually and I don't want this. I tried to prevent user gestures by changing the pivot control's IsHitTestVisible property to false and although it stops the user changing the pivot page, it also prevents the use of the textbox inside.

Does anybody know how to prevent the user changing the pivot page, but still allow use of the controls inside?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) has a control for this ([LockablePivot](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-LockablePivot-in-depth)).