# Stop sliding from one side in WP7 Pivot

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, pivot

I'm using pivot in my application to show a group of images , i want to stop left or right sliding in the pivot to the user can not navigate back .How can i do that?

```
     <controls:Pivot Title="TITLE"   Margin="0,0,0,60">

        <controls:PivotItem >
            <Grid>

                <Image Source="/src" />
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <controls:PivotItem>
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="/src"  />
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
        <controls:PivotItem >
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="/src" />
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
        <controls:PivotItem >
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="/src" />
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>



    </controls:Pivot>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480124/restrict-back-navigation-in-pivot/12495582#12495582

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pivot without navigation purposes, you can just create a page or usercontrol to fit your needs. If you only want to prevent manual control of the pivot, see this question:
[Prevent manual control of pivot control movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848089/prevent-manual-control-of-pivot-control-movement)

Comment: thank you but i want to use a pivot, i just want to lock the first image only so the user can not go to the last image from the first one.